# Find the differences between two noisy, lighting variant images (histogram alignment and more)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to extract a single object from a picture taken by a camera. A picture of the camera's view without the object exists. The camera's focus does not change, but the lighting does when an object is in view. The object is solid but not of constant shade of gray. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVWWr.png) is a picture of the reference image on the right and another image with an object on the left. The pictures are monochrome.

All the processing is happening after the image acquisition and computation time is not a big issue. The precision of the algorithm is more important.

Most questions I have found here deal with the question if two pictures are similar or not, but I am interested in finding the region that the object occupies in the image for subsequent measurements.

So far, I have tried different combinations of subtracting and then binarizing the blurred images with a threshold, but this is not lighting invariant. Multiplying the reference image beforehand by the relative lighting difference does not yield satisfactory results either. Maybe it could work if a better way to simulate a different exposure is used.

I have also tried subtracting the LoG filtered images and a few crude neighborhood pixel comparisons without success.

It feels like a very intuitive task that some kind of descriptor comparison should be able to handle, but I am struggling to find a good solution. Does anyone know of a good method that I've been missing?

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks to Franco Callari's answer, I stumbled upon [histogram matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching) which to my surprise wasn't covered by ready-made OpenCV functions. Since this seems like a common problem, I might as well post my inefficient hack-up here in case someone wants to use it.

```
// Aligns the histogram of the source image to match that of the target image. 
// Both are evaluated in a ROI, not across the whole picture.
// The function assumes 8-bit grayscale images.
static void alignHistogram(Mat alignsource, const Mat& aligntarget, 
    const int rowstart = 500, const int rowend = 700, 
    const int colstart = 0, const int colend = 1000)    
{   
    // 1) Calculate target and source histogram in region of interest
    // 2) Compute the integral of each histogram (cumulative distribution function)
    // 3) Set brightness of each pixel in the source image to the brightness of the target where the CDF values are equal

    Mat ROIsource = alignsource(Range(rowstart, rowend), Range(colstart, colend));
    Mat ROItarget = aligntarget(Range(rowstart, rowend), Range(colstart, colend));
    MatND hist_source, hist_target;

    int bins = 256, int histSize[] = {bins};
    float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };        const float* ranges[] = { sranges };
    int channels[] = {0};
    calcHist( &ROItarget, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_target, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    calcHist( &ROItarget, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_source, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false );

    Mat CDF_target_2d, CDF_source_2d; 
    integral(hist_target, CDF_target_2d);
    integral(hist_source, CDF_source_2d);
    Mat CDF_target = CDF_target_2d.col(1),  CDF_source = CDF_source_2d.col(1);

    // Cycle through source image inefficiently and adjust brightness
    for (int i = 0; i < alignsource.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < alignsource.cols; j++)
        {
            int source_brightness = alignsource.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
            double cdf_source_value = CDF_source.at<double>(source_brightness);

            int target_brightness = 0;
            while (target_brightness < 256) {
                if (CDF_target.at<double>(target_brightness) > cdf_source_value)
                    break;
                target_brightness++;
            }
            alignsource.at<unsigned char>(i, j) = target_brightness;
        }
    }
}
```

Adjusting the lighting helps to get a better first guess of the object, but it"s not enough to get a precise contour, especially when the background is not very different from the object or rich in features. That's as far as I got at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the the camera is not moved nor the background changed (as it appears from the sample photo), the difference in global illumination is likely due (for the most part) to either of two factors - camera with auto-exposure making a different choice of f/stop or exposure time when the subject is in the scene, or a time-varying light source within the exposure time window (e.g. 60Hz line hum in the lamp). The latter is to be excluded if the illuminator is a strobe (and enough time between shots is given for the strobe to recharge).

I say "for the most part" above because, with the subject taking up a large portion of the frame, light reflected from it does affect global illumination as well, but in your case this is likely a second order effect.

Your best approach is likely to be to better control the capture - at a minimum, disable auto-exposure in the camera, use a ballasted light (if it's not a strobe).

If you cannot (or in addition), you should start with global histogram alignment, rather than equalization. Global histogram equalization, as suggested by other posters, is likely to hurt, because the subject's pixel values will be part of the histogram, not just the background. However, if the camera is not moved, you can pre-identify in the image frame regions that are known to be background, and sample the histogram only from them in both the "background only" and "with subject" images. You can then find the values at, say, the top and bottom 5% of the dynamic range, and just apply a global scaling to they match.

Comment: I completely agree. Controlling the exposure will probably not work in this case because the object considerably affects the illumination of the setup - adjusting for it seems to be the best approach.
Sadly, I haven't found any tutorials or function in OpenCV for aligning two images' histograms. I will update my post later with some code when I hacked something together. If you have any resources on histogram alignment, I'd be glad to get some pointers!

Comment: The "alignment" I'd start with is a simple linear scaling. Compute the pixel values at the 5% and 95% of the histogram in both images: they define the "effective dynamic range" of the two images (of course you can play a bit with the boundaries, 5 and 95 are just good places to start), then compute the shift and scale that, when applied to image 2, make its effective dynamic range equal to that of image 1. You can try it in Gimp or Photoshop for a few sample images ("adjust levels..."), and see how well it'd work without having to write a single line of code.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I started by implementing what amounts to a look-up table following [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching) procedure, and a simple shift by the average difference in brightness in the reference area. You can see the results in [these pictures](http://imgur.com/a/zDain). Strangely, the simplest of those methods seems to have worked best.

I marked your post as the accepted answer because this is evidently the right first step, although obscured details in the reference picture still make the distinction of the different regions difficult.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use histogram equalization ( cvEqualizeHist() function in OpenCV). It will help you to eliminate the difference of lightings.

2) You will have two almost identical images (image without object and with object, other parts must be identical, because camera is static). Take their difference by function

```
void cvSub(
    const CvArr* src1,
    const CvArr* src2,
    CvArr*       dst,
    const CvArr* mask  = NULL)
```

3) The result must be the following: the place, where object is located will be almost white, rest of the image will not be as bright. Use

```
void cvInRangeS(
    const CvArr* src,
    CvScalar     lower,
    CvScalar     upper,
    CvArr*       dst
);
```

This function can be used to check if the pixels in an image fall within a particular specified range. So take a range that is close to white (for example (200, 255)).

4) Find the edge of the object remaining in the image with

```
int cvFindContours(
  IplImage*              img,
  CvMemStorage*          storage,
  CvSeq**                firstContour,
  int                    headerSize  = sizeof(CvContour),
  CvContourRetrievalMode mode        = CV_RETR_LIST,
  CvChainApproxMethod    method      = CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
);
```

Comment: As Franco Callari noted, using equalizeHist includes the object in view and does not yield good results. You can see the equalized images and the result of the subtraction [here](http://imgur.com/a/ubMt2).

Answer (score 0):

If illumination is time variant, you can utilize hue information in HSV or HSI space, hue may prove to be strongly invariant to illumination. If your image is grayscale then you can try some histogram equalization

Comment: Sadly, the image is in grayscale. I should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with:

(i) Histogram equalization
(ii) Subtraction of the two images (if the reference object really doesn't change its position
(iii) Opening (Erosion, Dilation), try different mask sizes (3x3, 5x5)

Then have a look at the resulting image. How much "garbage" is left. If there are too many connected pixels outside your area of interest you might need to increase the mask for the opening (or maybe for the erosion only). The you might binarize the image and take the binary as mask to filter out the area of interest in the original.

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to use background subtraction algorithms. Though mostly used for video sequences, should be fine. I suggest you the [Code Book Method](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=OPencv%20codebook%20method&source=bl&ots=hSJ4egkDOd&sig=V7pHt9Z25HfYePHO1mmWB-mfsbg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MARbUeCeBImRswbYlICIDA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=OPencv%20codebook%20method&f=false) from opencv

1. Give the codebook method your input image
2. You have variables to adjust telling the codebook method how many frames it must take
   in  as background, in your case this would be one.
3. The resultant is a foreground image, and a background image.
4. You can then use smoothing to clear out some noise.
5. Use foreground image which should contain your object (assuming the finger is what you want to find)
6. Find the contour using opencv methods.

Hope this helps

Comment: That link gives a 404 and I sadly just lent out my Learning OpenCV book, but as far as I can see, the foreground extraction based on a single background image would basically be a pixel-per-pixel comparison with a tolerance, i.e. a simple subtraction and a threshold operation. Am I mistaken? Because in that case it doesn't seem like it would perform well on these images, seeing as there is no moving background but a good deal of lighting variance. It is an interesting method to keep in mind if I want to use a set of background images with different lighting conditions, though.

Comment: Well you might be right, but it is also averaging its input, accumulating differences, then throwing out foreground, background. I have fixed the link.